# Non-Ideal Gas Question

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, gas, volume

I have been attempting to solve a problem involving a non-ideal gas. The gas is assumed to be non-ideal and hence modelled by the Van der Waals Equation, it is considered to be pure hydrogen gas and is contained in a cylinder that has a changing length and fixed radius, hence the volume can be changed and is not fixed.

I am trying to calculate the pressure and temperature at a given volume, I understand that the pressure and temperature will increase at their own rates $dP/dV$ and $dT/dV$ when the volume decreases, though the only formula I have is the non-ideal gas equation:

$$(p+((an^2)/V))(V-nb) = nRT.$$

Hence I cannot simply remove one of the variables to try to find values of another and I do not have equations for $dP/dV$ or $dT/dV$.

I began looking at trying ways to find values for $dP/dV$ and $dT/dV$. First, I tried using the non-ideal gas equation and deriving either $dP/dV$ or $dT/dV$ from this but I could not solve them without having all three variables present, (which is the initial problem).

Instead, I began looking at other peoples work and potentially using graphs of $P$ against $V$ or $T$ against $V$ to formulate a function and then work backwards to determine an accurate differential $dP/dV$ or $dT/dV$. Unfortunetly using this method did not seem to work as the gas that I was researching (Hydrogen) seemed to have no such graphs or data available.

Hence I am now stuck and asking for assistance with my problem. If anyone can offer help in finding a method to link the dynamic system together that would be greatly appreciated.

I believe that the key to finding the solution lies in finding a numerical answer for $dP/dV$ and or $dT/dV$.

Comment: If you know how the internal energy $U$ changes according to net work and heating, perhaps you can apply the general equation $dU=nc_V\,dT+(\alpha TK-P)dV$, which applies to all gases. Here $c_V$ is the constant-volume molar heat capacity, $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient, and $K$ is the bulk modulus.

Comment: Hi, welcome to physics StackExchange. Is the process adiabatic? Is heat being lost to the environment? Are pressures high enough so you have a mixture of gas and liquid H2? Is energy conserved? Is exergy conserved? I think you need Cengel's [book](https://www.amazon.com/thermodynamics-engineering-approach-CENGEL/dp/9353165741/ref=pd_sbs_4/135-0597693-1488537?pd_rd_w=suU4S&pf_rd_p=3676f086-9496-4fd7-8490-77cf7f43f846&pf_rd_r=SKVMKJMRK85NKT8XZ1T9&pd_rd_r=5b4f687a-b8c3-4b00-901d-4c16b3e0c0e5&pd_rd_wg=wlScx&pd_rd_i=9353165741&psc=1).

Comment: Substitute the given volume into the equation.  You then have the pressure as a function of temperature.  Simple as that.

Comment: @ChetMiller, no, there are a lot of details we are not being told about, so perhaps its not that simple.

Comment: What is the exact statement of the problem?

Comment: Hi @Chemomechanics, I believe that would work, though I have not got an expression for how the internal energy changes, is there another way to find this out? I have given all information about my problem above, if there is another equation or potentially a table of values for hydrogen under certain conditions i could use this method.

Comment: Hi @Arc, yes the process is adiabatic in a way as the only temperature change would be due to a pressure change which would come from a change in volume. In this model, I am assuming that it is a pure hydrogen gas that has no heat energy losses, hence no liquid H2 will form.

Comment: @ChetMiller, Unfortunately, this brings me back to the same problem. I am trying to find what the pressure is at a certain volume and then also find what will happen to the temperature due to that pressure, hence the only known value is volume.

Comment: Are you asking for dU as a function of dT and dV?

Comment: HI @Chet Miller, i am not asking for dU instead looking for a way of calculating the pressure and temperature at a given volume, my problem is that i am not sure what the pressure and temperature will change by whenever the volume changes.

Comment: I give up.  I asked for the exact wording of the problem, but you resist providing it.

Comment: @Chet Miller, this is not a written question, instead of my own quiere.

Answer (score 1):

If the process is adiabatic and reversible, then $$dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV=0\tag{1}$$with $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V=\frac{nC_v}{T}\tag{2}$$and,from $dF=-SdT-PdV$ and the related Maxwell relation, $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=\frac{nR}{V-nb}\tag{3}$$From Eqns. 2 and 3 it follows that Cv is a function only of temperature, so that it must equal Cv in the ideal gas limit $C_v(T,V)=C_v^{IG}(T)$Therefore, from the above equations, we have:  $$\frac{C_v^{IG}}{T}dT=-\frac{R}{V-nb}dV$$This can be integrated directly to give T as a function of V.

Comment: Up to my rusty thermodynamic skills, this is the answer. Nice to think again about Maxwell's relations.

Comment: This seems to make sense, cheers aye.